# using bit shifting variables inside if statement - error or not

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, bit-shift

Suppose we have some variables x and y, and the following if statement which involves bit shifting:

```
if (x<<y)
```

I've read some posts which also deal with the issue of using bit shifting with variables (of some type) and inside if statement, but unfortunately I haven't been able to reach a unequivocal conclusion whether it is an error or not.

I assume that  if it is an error, then it's a semantic error or a run-time error .

But is it necessarily en error ?

Comment: It's not an error by itself. The question is what you are expecting from it (well, and what are the types and values involved).

Comment: @EugeneSh. why it's not semantic or run-time error ?

Comment: Because it is not. Why would it be? `x << y` is an expression which is evaluated and giving a certain result. Then this result is interpreted as condition for `if` statement.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and about the fact that x and y are integers in this case, and not unsigned?

Comment: Then it's matter of their values. The answer down there is giving the reference to the limitations involved.

Comment: This is not an error of any kind. It might not be a particularly *useful* construction, but there's nothing at all wrong with it.

Comment: This could be construed as a typo by another developer.  Using `if ((x << y) != 0)` would make it explicit what you're intending to do.  (Although in that case I'd be inclined to use a bit mask test.)

Comment: Regarding your edit, the body of the `if` has no bearing on the condition.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to add other questions. People entered answers in good faith, and modifying the question renders them invalid or incomplete. Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of questions and answers for anybody to use, not a personal problem-solving service. By modifying a question, you cause the answers to be mismatched, making Stack Overflow less useful for people who find this question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is of an unsigned integer type that is at least as large as `unsigned int`, and `y` is less than the number of bits in `x`'s type, then the above partial statement will test whether bits in `x` that *aren't* in the top `y` are set.  The C89 Standard would require that implementations behave likewise if `x` is of a signed type or a small unsigned type, with the caveat that setting the top bit of a small signed type is regarded as setting all bits beyond.  The C99 and later standards, however, wouldn't require that implementations usefully process any situation in which `x` is non-zero but the expression `x<<y` would yield zero, unless `x` is an unsigned integer type at least as large as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a syntactic error. `if` expects a parenthesized expression. `(int_x<<int_y)` satisfies that. The shift expression may cause a runtime error, but only if the particular values of `int_x` and `int_y` invoke undefined behavior (see [6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7) for when that might happen).

Comment: suppose we have 3 optional answers as following : 1) it is a semantic error.  2) it is a run-time error 3) it is not an error   -then you would choose the last option ?  @PSkocik

Comment: @galik Probably. Yeah.