# if statement which involves bit shifting of variables - error or not (update )

Tags: c, if-statement, runtime-error, bit-shift

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57103312/2410359) I asked in this forum , whether it is an error or not to use the following if statement which involves bit shifting of given x and  y:

```
if (x<<y)
```

**The conclusive answer for that question what that the statement as written above is not any kind of error , not a run-time error as well.**

Suppose we would expand the scope of that question and  rewrite the statement above to be the following one instead:

```
if (x<<y) x++;
```

in this case, would it still have no error of any kind ( including run-time error) ?

Comment: @AkshitAchara I don't think that's entirely fair. C does have it's subtle issues...

Comment: It is not clear why you are asking. For the most part, the answer is obvious to people who know a modest amount of C—it is akin to asking whether snapping two Lego pieces together is okay. Sure, it is fine. Maybe you have some question about whether the `++` operator is okay in this situation, since it is notoriously troublesome in certain situations? If so, you should state that explicitly in your question. It is not a problem here; the controlling expression of an `if` is a full expression, so it has a sequence point after it, so there is no issue about sequencing of side effects.

Comment: Note that what is fine, and does not generate any error, is the mere use of `x++` with the `x<<y`, assuming they are otherwise okay. If instead we ask whether there could be any complications in this statement due to other circumstances, the answer is yes: `x++` could overflow (either overflow an integer type or exceed array bounds of a pointer type). `y` could have an invalid value for the shift amount. `x<<y` could overflow. `x` could have a type that is invalid for a shift operand (for example, it could be a structure). `y` could be a preprocessor macro that expands to something untoward…

Comment: There is also a concern that you are asking excessively simple questions that somebody just learning C might not understand yet. If you are just learning C, then a better way to proceed is to continue reading and working on exercises in a textbook. It will answer most of your questions and hopefully bring you to the point where you can figure out answers for yourself or look them up. It is good to be inquisitive, but there should be a balance about expending some effort of your own to learn before involving others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any surrounding context, it is impossible to tell if this code will have any run-time errors:

```
if (x<<y) x++;
```

We don't know the types or values of `x` or `y`, nor do we know what the code is expected to do. So the closest thing to an answer we can give you is, "We don't know."

Comment: Yes. We also don't know the type of `x` or `y` - e.g. if `y` is a `float` then you can expect some trouble. However; if we know `if (x<<y)` is OK, then we can say `if (x<<y) x++;` is also OK (or at least that I can't think of a case where the former is OK and the latter not).